# haskell understanding data type

Tags: haskell

Assume that we have next data:

```
data Value =
IntVal Int
| BoolVal Bool
```

and function

```
f :: Value -> Int
```

How can I separate cases on different constructors on argument of type Value?
So `f (IntVal 1)` has one behaviour and `f (BoolVal True)` has some another behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different methods a popular one is to use pattern matching in a function parameter.

```
negateValue :: Value -> Value
negateValue (IntVal  n) = IntVal  (-n)
negateValue (BoolVal p) = BoolVal (not p)
```

Another method would be to use case patterns.

Using case:

```
negateValue val = case val of
    IntVal  n -> IntVal  (-n)
    BoolVal p -> BoolVal (not p)
```

Comment: @capoluca you may want to read about 'pattern matchin' in general. One place to start is the [wikibook entry on the topic](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching).

Comment: @capoluca This is also some times call deconstructing data types. Another great resource is [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com) you might want to check out its [section on pattern matching.](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching)

Comment: Or the Gentle Introduction to Haskell.  It's like 10 pages long and covers all of the standard language features.